# php cURL request causing session deadlock

Tags: php, session, deadlock

I have a request that uses the session to check to see if a user is authenticated.  Then from that request I am making a cURL request (that needs to be authenticated) using the session variables.

The issue is the first request waits until the cURL request completes, and the cURL request can't start the session until the initial request completes. I hit a deadlock causing both requests to time out.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Release session file before trying to read it from another process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After updating the session in the first script,
use `session_write_close();` to remove the lock from the file.

In PHP 7 you can remove the lock immediately after reading:

```
session_start([
    'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    'read_and_close'  => true,
]);
```

HHVM does this by default.

An even better approach would be to use a non-locking session handler like memcache.